# How to set an offset to AWT Image or Swing ImageIcon?

Tags: java, image, swing, user-interface, offset

I want to initialize an `ImageIcon` with an offset. The resizing is already working properly, but how can I tell the resized image icon to map to a certain `x and y` coordinate?

I have a map in my project and the attached snippet is the initialization of the image icon.

The image icon is then printed to a `JLabel` with a static size and position.

```
ImageIcon imageIcon = createImageIcon("/mapEnd1.png", "Map");
Image image = imageIcon.getImage();
Image newimg = image.getScaledInstance(600, 800,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH); 
imageIcon = new ImageIcon(newimg);
```

Comment: Since your code is creating an image at run-time, apply the offset to a newly created, blank image. *"..with a static size and position"* That sounds a lot like a `null` layout. Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: thank you for your comment, I was looking for specific the method to add a offset to a image. The offset I would use as moveable zoom function on my map-picture. 
the size of my Label may be static but I combined numerous layout-types in the whole project
and as always ALL GLORY TO THE HYPNOTOAD